# add values to multiple columns in one go with new index - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['w','x','y','z'])
```

I'm trying to insert a new index row by row, and add values to certain columns.
If I were adding one value to a specific column, I could do: `df.loc['a','x'] =  2`

However what if I'd like to add values to several columns in one go, like this:

```
{'x':2, 'z':3}
```

is there a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d,index=['a']).combine_first(df)
    w  x   y  z
a NaN  2 NaN  3
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what OP wants.  **HOWEVER** I think that is clever.

Answer (score 2):

#### `reindex` and `assign`

```
df.reindex(['a']).assign(**d)

     w  x    y  z
a  NaN  2  NaN  3
```

Where:

```
d = {'x':2, 'z':3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` but selecting multiple columns and assign an iterable (like a list or tuple)

```
df.loc['a',['x','z']] = [2,3]
```

Or as suggested from @jfaccioni, in case the data is a dictionary `d`:

```
df.loc['a', list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())
```

Comment: OP could also do `df.loc['a', list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())` if the dictionary structure is preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the edit to reflect both ways.